# Calling pure virtual function from thread in child class throws exception

Tags: c++, multithreading, inheritance, c++11, virtual

I have a child class that starts a method of the base class as a thread. The child class has also implemented a pure virtual method from the base class. The thread then needs to call the child's implemented version of the pure virtual method in the thread, but the thread throws an exception: "Pure virtual method called." The code below demonstrates what happens on construction of a Child:

```
class Base {
  std::thread messageThread;

  virtual void processMessage(std::string msg) = 0;

  static void checkForMessages(Base *c) {
    while(true) {
      std::string msg = "Hello";
      c->processMessage(msg);
    }
  }
};

class Child : public Base {
  Child() {
    messageThread = std::thread(checkForMessages, this);
  }

  void processMessage(std::string msg) {
     std::cout << "Message: " << msg << std::endl;
  }
};
```

My understanding is that Child is still considered a Base until after the constructor finishes, so the thread is only able to see processMessage as a pure virtual function. I could implement checkForMessages for every child of Base, but that defeats the purpose of having the Base class in the first place.

How can I implement this correctly? Thank you for the help!

Edit: A complete example that demonstrates the issue, with an attempted fix: https://gist.github.com/4590476

Comment: Your question would make more sense if `Child` actually inherited from `Base`... ;-]

Comment: True! Fixed in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing stops the instance of `Derived` from being destroyed (or at least starting to be) before the thread runs.  You need some smart pointers or some synchronization.

Comment: Thank you! My understanding (correct me if I'm wrong): the thread is getting spun up, but since the deconstructor is called right away, processMessage reverts back to Base's version, throwing the exception. So a solution would be to force the thread to join in the Child's destructor. Correct?

Comment: Mayhap.  But blocking in general should be avoided: if the thread is going away that quickly, why spin up a thread?

Comment: While I agree that starting in the ctor isn't the best of ideas, it is up to you to decide that for your particular case. However, in your scenario, if you start it in the ctor, you must stop it in the dtor or before. And, just like with starting, stopping must happen in the derived class, not in the base-class! If you want to inherit the stop-start functionality, consider writing a template wrapping any class with a run() method or something similar. The important point is that the class doing the stuff must be the inner or base class, so that it outlives the enclosing class' thread.

Answer (score 3):

You could move `std::thread(checkForMessages, this)` into a separate `start()` method that must be invoked by the caller after the object's been constructed.

Comment: If desired, you can make the constructor `private` or `protected` and have a public wrapper function that constructs a class member and calls its `start()` method.

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't fix anything. I added a method start() to Child that start the thread, and I call start() by whatever creates the Child class. So Child is fully created before the thread is started. The same exception is thrown by the thread.

Comment: @Albeit: To be frank, that doesn't make a lot of sense. There must have been something wrong with your implementation. Could you post the code?

Comment: Sure thing, here is the actual code, with a significant amount deleted, but most just straight copied https://gist.github.com/4590306

Comment: @Albeit: I am not sure how this compiles, but unless `Json::Value` is `std::string`, you're not overriding the pure virtual function.

Comment: Full program that compiles that demonstrates the issue: https://gist.github.com/4590476

Answer (score 1):

There are clearly many ways of solving this. My suggestion would be to use two classes: one to wrap the thread, and one to implement your "check message".

```
lass Base {
  std::thread messageThread;

  virtual void processMessage(std::string msg) = 0;

  static void checkForMessages(Base *c) {
    while(true) {
      std::string msg = "Hello";
      c->processMessage(msg);
    }
  }
};

class Child : public Base {
  Child() {
  }

  void processMessage(std::string msg) {
     std::cout << "Message: " << msg << std::endl;
  }
};

class ThreadWrapper
{
    ThreadWrapper(Base *b)
    {
        messageThread = std::thread(Base::checkForMessages, this);
    }
    ... 
}

....
Child child;
ThreadWrapper tw(&child);
```

The other rather obvious choice is to start the thread in a separate member function.

If neither of these are "good", then you may want to explain why, and we can probably come up with some other ideas.

Here's a couple of snippets for "how to start a thread from a different function":

class Child: public Base
    public:
        Child() {
        }

```
    void start(void) { messageThread = std::thread(checkForMessages, this); }


    ~Child() {
        messageThread.join();
    }
```

....

```
int main()
{
    Child c;
    c.start();
```

I also modified the checkForMessage to exit after a while. Works in my test-case.

Comment: Hi Mats, thanks for the advice. Starting the thread in a separate function is completely acceptable, but I can't seem to get it working. I've commented to the top-ranked answer to consolidate the answers with a working program that demonstrates the exception.